# Rotating other 3D vectors based on one vector's image

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations

I have an initial, normalised 3D vector $\vec n$ and its result after an unknown rotation, $\vec n'$. Given another normalised 3D vector $\vec \omega$, is there a vector formula for getting its image $\vec \omega'$ under that same rotation? I'm imagining that mapping $\vec n$ to $\vec n'$ is like rotating the unit sphere, which *should* allow easily remapping every vector on the sphere. On the other hand, since we're rotating, it probably isn't as easy as doing a projection, unlike e.g. the vector formulas for the [law of reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619594/219950) and [refraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435512/snells-law-in-vector-form).

Comment: Knowing the image of one vector in 3D under a rotation isn't enough to determine the rotation, since rotations around $n'$ as an axis don't affect the vector $n'$. Are you looking for a specific rotation, such as rotating around an axis perpendicular to $n$ and $n'$ by the angle between $n$ and $n'$?

Comment: Transformation of just one vector is not enough to uniquely determine the rotation.

Comment: @TomKern That would be fine in my case, yes. Any rotation around $\vec n'$ is okay as long as it is applied equally to all vectors when transformed this way.

Comment: You can use Rodrigues' Rotation Formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula to rotate around a vector. Are you okay figuring out the unit vector to rotate around and the angle to rotate by?

Comment: @TomKern If the given vectors are both normalised, how about $\vec k = \vec n \times \vec n'$ and $\theta = \arccos(\vec n \cdot \vec n')$?